# Django auth error on azure sql server, can't find object (table)

Tags: python, sql-server, django, django-rest-framework

I'm currently building a custom api auth path on django rest framework, the application is connected to azure sql-server.
the connexion to the database works perfectly, the table and migrations have been applied to the database, the necessary table have been filled with the necessary column and data, Django Admin tables such as  `auth_user`, `auth_user_groups`, `auth_group`, `auth_permission` etc...

A `python3 startapp users` was launched to customize my login class.

users/models.py :

```
 from django.conf import settings from django.dispatch import receiver
 from django.db.models.signals import post_save from
 rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token from
 django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser from django.db import models

 
 class User(AbstractUser): 
     def __str__(self):
         return self.username
  
 @receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL) def
 create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
     if created:
         Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

The user model is serialized

users/serializers.py :

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import User

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id','username','first_name','last_name','email')
```

users/views.py :

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import ObtainAuthToken
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .models import User
from .serializers import UserSerializer

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = []


class UserLogIn(ObtainAuthToken):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data = request.data,
                                            context = {'request':request})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        token = Token.objects.get(user=user)
        return Response({
            'token': token.key,
            'id': user.pk,
            'username': user.username
        })
```

urls :

```
path('api-user-login/', UserLogIn.as_view()),
```

settings :

```
> AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
```

On post on the auth login pass i get a

```
ProgrammingError at /api-user-login/
('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'users_user'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

> Request Method:   POST Request
> URL:  http://localhost:8000/api-user-login/ Django Version:   4.1.7
> Exception Type:   ProgrammingError Exception Value:    ('42S02', "[42S02]
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object
> name 'users_user'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)") Raised
> during:   users.views.UserLogIn

Comment: Have you tried either `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.models.User'` or just simply `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'User'`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning `AUTH_USER_MODEL must be of the form 'app_label.model_name'`

Comment: String model references must be of the form 'app_label.ModelName'.